# ExceptionBug in java project?

Tags: java, exception

This is my goal: Write a program that converts from 24-hour time to 12-hour time. The exception should catch anything that has minute above 59, but trying a couple of right entries I entered 10:65 and the exception caught it but it returned the output of the last time after catching - "That is the same as" " last time". Why is that?

This is the program:

```
package programmingProject;

import java.util.*;

public class TimeConverter
{
    private String input;

    public TimeConverter()
    {
        input = null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TimeConverter user = new TimeConverter();
        user.handleTime();
    }
    public void handleTime()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        try{
        System.out.println("Enter time in 24-hour notation:");
        input = keyboard.next();
        checkValidity(input);
        }

        catch(TimeFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }



    }

    public void checkValidity(String input) throws TimeFormatException
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(input.charAt(2) != ':' && input.length() != 5)
        {
            throw new TimeFormatException();
        }
        else
        {
            int hour;
            int minutes;
            char recheck = 'y';
            hour = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,2));
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(3));

            if((hour <0 || hour >=23) || ((minutes<0)) || (minutes >59))
            {
                throw new TimeFormatException();
            }
            else 
            {
                while(recheck == 'y')
                {
                    if(hour <12 || minutes <59)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That is the same as \n" + input + " AM");
                        System.out.println("Again?(y/n)");
                        recheck = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                        if(recheck == 'y')
                        {
                            handleTime();
                        }
                        else if(recheck == 'n')
                        {
                            System.out.println("End of program");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong input");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int newHour = hour - 12;
                        String newMinute;

                        if(minutes<10)
                            newMinute = "0" + Integer.toString(minutes);
                        else
                        {
                            newMinute = Integer.toString(minutes);
                        }


                        System.out.println("That is the same as \n" 
                                            + newHour+ ':' + newMinute + " PM");
                        System.out.println("Again?(y/n)");
                        recheck = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                        if(recheck == 'y')
                        {
                            handleTime();
                        }
                        else if(recheck == 'n')
                        {
                            System.out.println("End of program");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong input");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }



    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
package programmingProject;

public class TimeFormatException extends Exception
{
    public TimeFormatException()
    {
        super("The format of the time is wrong!");
    }

    public TimeFormatException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit further! What exceptions did you get exactly,more precisely.

Comment: My question is how do I prevent an entry like 10:65 from returning the output of the previous entry after the exception is called

Comment: Can you show us how you are using your program in order to reproduce the issue + the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: However, there is room in your code for improvement. 1) input does not need to be a field, you are always using it as a local variable - parameter / 2) there seems to be sections of your code - specifically when you ask the user if he wants to input something else - that are copy-pasted at least twice, consider extracting those to a new private method and calling it twice instead of duplicating the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted your code a bit and seems tally with your requirement.

```
public void handleTime() {

System.out.println("Enter time in 24-hour notation:");

        calc();

    }

    public void calc() {
        char recheck = 'y';
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {

                input = keyboard.next();
                if (input.charAt(2) != ':' && input.length() != 5) {
                    throw new TimeFormatException();
                } else {
                    int hour;
                    int minutes;

                    hour = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 2));
                    minutes = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(3));

                    if ((hour < 0 || hour >= 23) || ((minutes < 0))
                            || (minutes > 59)) {
                        throw new TimeFormatException();
                    } else {
                        if (hour < 12) {
                            System.out.println("That is the same as \n" + input
                                    + " AM");
                            System.out.println("Again?(y/n)");
                            recheck = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                        } else {
                            int newHour = hour - 12;
                            String newMinute;

                            if (minutes < 10)
                                newMinute = "0" + Integer.toString(minutes);
                            else {
                                newMinute = Integer.toString(minutes);
                            }

                            System.out.println("That is the same as \n"
                                    + newHour + ':' + newMinute + " PM");
                            System.out.println("Again?(y/n)");
                            recheck = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (TimeFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Again?(y/n)");
                recheck = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            }
        } while (recheck == 'y');

        if (recheck == 'n') {
            System.out.println("End of program");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

Bit of advice :). I strongly suggest you to debug with a IDE and then you will see how good enough you are to find answers for this kind of problems and will make you a better programmer.